# No log is being printed in log file, but it is getting printed on cosole [log4j]

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to implement log4j in my java project, I created log4j.properties under directory target/classes/log4j.properties

Below is my properties file content

```
#Root logger option 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, Rollfile

#Direct log messages to file
log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\TestLogger\\azuremigrationclient_log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

My logs are getting printed in my console out, but the logging file "azuremigrationclient_log.log" is coming empty. Nothing is getting logged there.

Answer (score 1):

I went through some docs and found that I did not specify the path to log4j.properties, which is why console was able to print the log but no logs were getting printed in the log file (no file getting created either)

```
static {
 PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
}
```

Add the above code to your class and inside configure, give path to your log4j.
eg - E:\JavaCodeDemo\testcases\classes\log4j.properties.

It will work. Your code was not able to find the log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

I read the comments and answers and I think this could happen if you're trying to use Log4j2 with a Log4j configuration file (log4j.properties). Your configuration is really for Log4j, only missing `log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`, as someone already suggested. You should stick with Log4j2 and change your configuration as per its documentation (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), e.g.

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = info

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = E:\\TestLogger\\azuremigrationclient_log.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = E:\\TestLogger\\azuremigrationclient-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i_log.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Answer (score 0):

you reference in the rootLogger configuration is called `Rollfile` while your identifier for the Appender is called `file`. This does not match. Compare to the usage of `stdout` in your config file.

1: your type configuration is missing e.g.:

```
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

2: You should try to name the reference from `Rollfile` to `file`

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
```

OR rename all your `file` identifiers for the configurations to `Rollfile`:

```
log4j.appender.Rollfile.File=E:\\TestLogger\\azuremigrationclient_log.log
log4j.appender.Rollfile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.Rollfile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.Rollfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Rollfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

side note: log4j is a heavily outdated library which is no longer maintained. This means no bug-fixed or any other updates and it contains a couple of reported security vulnerabilities. If you are in control of the project and are able to choose your logging library, you should switch to something more up to date e.g. `Log4j2`. It has some API breaking incompatible changes, but more or less it's the successor for Log4j 1.x

Comment: I updated the rollfile to file, but the log file is still empty. I followed a tutorial but still facing the issue, on console the log is getting printed okay

Comment: your appender type configuration is missing:
`log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`

Comment: I added it, still nothing coming to log file,

Comment: does it has to do something with log file path? not able to find the log file.

Comment: The file will be created from log4j, but the program must have write access on the path.

Comment: oh, I already created the file. I thought I need to specify the file before hand, and the code will just use the same file and append it.

Comment: I removed the file, so that program will create it, no file was created.

Comment: I  gave full permission to myself (both read and write permission) still no file was created